# iPhone and App Certificates and APPID''s

Tags: iphone, certificate, distribution, app-id

So I have a few questions here.

I started doing App development a while ago and am starting to submit Applications.  And my question site mostly around the APPId's.  Reason I am asking is because I am getting signing error's, and I think this is why.

```
com.Company1.App1
com.Company2.App2
```

or

```
com.MyCompany.App1
com.MyCompany.App2
```

I am using the format of `com.MyCompany.App1` and `com.MyCompany.App2`, and I have recently created the APP ID's and provisioning profiles, have them installed, have them selected in Build Settings for Distribution.  I have restarted XCode done a Clean on the Apps before Building them.  But it keeps giving me the error and therefore I can't upload to the App Store.

Also, I assume you just create one Certificate for all your apps, using the Company Name you have in your App Developer Profile online...correct?

**UPDATE:** Here is the specific error message.  Also it's XCode 4 and when I goto Project->AppName->Build Settings, the correct Distribution profile is selected under Distribution.

```
Application failed codesign verification.  The signature was invalid, or it was not signed with an Apple submission certificate. (-19011)
```

Comment: Could you post the specific error message you're seeing as you don't mention it anywhere so it's going to be hard to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Target->yourapp->Get Info->Build in xcode and selected appropriate profile in code signing identity.

Let me know if you have any question.

Comment: No.For xcode 4 click on your project name on left panel and you will see middle panel - under Targets->project name ->Build setting.